# Ornstein-Uhlenbeck Process Initial Conditions

Tags: stochastic-processes

I know that the univariate Ornstein-Uhlenbeck process converges asymptotically to a normal distribution $N(\alpha, \frac{\sigma^2}{2 \beta})$ for constant initial conditions $X_0$.

I was wondering whether there are explicit solutions to the univariate (and multi-variate) Ornstein-Uhlenbeck when the initial conditions are normally distributed, i.e., $X_0 \sim N(\mu_0,\sigma_0)$.